# notify-osd not working after i3wm restart

Tags: ubuntu, i3, d-bus, notify-send

Notifications won't work after I restart i3wm (with super + shift + r).

My ubuntu version is 16.04 and I installed the patched notify-osd which allows customizable notifications.

From syslog I noticed it throws this line whenever notify-send gets called after the restart:

```
org.freedesktop.Notifications[2267]: ** (notify-osd:5204): WARNING **: dnd_is_idle_inhibited(): got error "The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files"
```

Is there anything I should be adding to my i3 config for example an *exec_always*?

Edit: I noticed the syslog warning is reported also before the restart, when notifications are still working, so it is likely not the reason.

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem, but I started using dunst as a notification manager and it works a lot better with i3, in case anybody wants to give it a shot